# Swift trailing constraint spacing depending on width of superview multiplied with a value (programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

Let's say I have a `UITableViewCell`.

In the `contentView` of the cell, I have a subView. The trailing of the subView to the `contentView` is depending on the width of the `contentView`, multiplied with a value.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
let trailingSpacing: CGFloat = contentView.frame.size.width * 0.2
subView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -trailingSpacing).isActive = true
```

The piece of code above is what I was trying to do in `layoutSubviews()` of the `UITableViewCell`. It's not working and besides that, it doesn't feel right. Is there a more clean way to do this? I don't think you can do this in 1 constraint, but maybe I'm wrong.

The constraints are alle done in code, there is no storyboard/xib/nib.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're able to solve it with a single constraint, but you can add a spacer view to solve this. Anchor the spacer view to the trailing of your container, and the trailing of your "target" view to the leading of the spacer. Then, give the spacer a width that's a multiple of the container's width:

```
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: spacer,
    attribute: .width,
    relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: container,
    attribute: .width,
    multiplier: 0.2, // <-- tweak this
    constant: 0
)
container.addConstraint(constraint)
```

(You may need to switch `space` and `container` in the constraint, I always forget which is the one the multiplier is applied to.)

You can even do this solution in Interface Builder.